# How to import an fbx in Unity correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, assets, blender, fbx

I've modelled an object and exported as fbx. After I import the asset in Unity, some artefacts show up. The artefacts seem to be related to Unity import and not do the fbx file as the model viewed in Windo3d 3d viever seem to have no issues.

Thank you a lot!

Object in Blender Edit mode

[image]

Object in Blender Object mode

[image]

Object in Windows 3d

[image]

Object in Unity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [triangle winding](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) problem. The order of the vertices in a triangle, when combined with their visual orientation, can be used to determine whether the triangle is being seen from the "front" or the "back" side. In Unity, by default triangles seen from the "back" are not rendered. This is called backface culling.

To fix this you have two options:

- Fix triangle windings in blender (by default in blender triangles seen from the "back" are rendered, look for backface culling option)
- Use a double sided material in Unity (a material that has a shader with [culling disabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html), i.e. `Cull Off`).