# When Importing From Blender To Unity Model is Missing Parts

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have made a model of a sword on blender and i want to use it on Unity. However when i import it into my scene a huge majority of faces are missing from the sword. I have looked at possible solutions but nothing seems to work (On Unity the Normals are on import). Below are images of the sword in blender and in my scene. What can i do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you import your model?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561826/how-to-import-an-fbx-in-unity-correctly/62562799#62562799) answer your question?

Comment: Looks like a backface culling issue due to normals not pointing outwards (not all in the camera direction) note that in reality even a sword is not only a single plane but has two sides and a certain thickness ;) Refer to the link Pluto provided. For debugging already in Blender you can turn Backface culling on there, then you have a better preview of what it will look like in Unity